# Switching Blogger Account to Custom Domain

Tags: hosting, blogger

I have a blogger account http://itsallabtamil.blogspot.com. I wish to host this at http://blog.jus4frnds.com. How to switch? I have created a CNAME record in my DNS Management for blog.jus4frnds.com to ghs.google.com. What else should I do? Should I Import my blog and upload it on my hosting?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the contents to new Platform is all your decision.If you want to customize the overall behavior of your blog which is not possible in Blog-spot than yes its good to move all content to the new platform.

But if you only want to change the domain name and not planning to do any major customization you can keep on using Blog-spot as you blogging platform and can use the new domain name.

I myself have done similar in which i have pointed my new domain to existing blog-spot platform but still i am using the blogger platform for writing new post and any other work,but as i am planning to move to WP so will move all the content to new platform to get more hold on overall look and feel of my Blog.

Choice is all your what you want with new platform